# Signature is invalid when executing Unbind in AssertionConsumerService

Tags: itfoxtec-identity-saml2

I implement a SAML service provider that is integrated with the Danish Unilogin IDP. I follow the example: https://github.com/ITfoxtec/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/tree/master/test/TestWebAppCore
When the AssertionConsumerService is executed (in the Unilogin test environment) I get the following exception:

ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2.Cryptography.InvalidSignatureException:
at ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2.Saml2Request.ValidateXmlSignature (ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2, Version=4.8.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=2dd6b1fbf7645f92)
at ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2.Saml2Request.Read (ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2, Version=4.8.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=2dd6b1fbf7645f92)
at ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2.Saml2Response.Read (ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2, Version=4.8.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=2dd6b1fbf7645f92)
at ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2.Saml2AuthnResponse.Read (ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2, Version=4.8.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=2dd6b1fbf7645f92)
at ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2.Saml2PostBinding.Read (ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2, Version=4.8.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=2dd6b1fbf7645f92)
at ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2.Saml2PostBinding.UnbindInternal (ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2, Version=4.8.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=2dd6b1fbf7645f92)
at ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2.Saml2Binding`1.Unbind (ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2, Version=4.8.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=2dd6b1fbf7645f92)
at Nebb.IdentityServer.Web.Controllers.AuthController+d__5.MoveNext (Nebb.IdentityServer.Web, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: /src/source/Nebb.IdentityServer.Web/Controllers/AuthController.cs:72)

I use the following parameters:

CertificateValidationMode = none

RevocationMode = NoCheck

IdPMetadataFile = https://viden.stil.dk/download/attachments/65503525/et-broker-IdP-metadata.xml?version=7&modificationDate=1578661325000&api=v2

Answer (score 0):

I have connected the ITfoxtec Identity SAML 2.0 component to the Danish Unilogin IdP with success.

Are you configuring the component by loading the Unilogin IdP metadata or doing the configuration yourself?

Is the response encrypted and the `saml2Configuration.DecryptionCertificate` not configured?
Configured like this:
https://github.com/ITfoxtec/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/blob/master/test/TestWebAppCoreNemLogin3Sp/Startup.cs#L34

Comment: Do you know what is the entry point for the external test entrypoint for uniLogin SAML?
I cannot find this information anywhere

Comment: Your signature validation error can be connected to the error resolved in https://github.com/ITfoxtec/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/releases/tag/4.8.6

Comment: To connect an application to UniLogin in danich https://viden.stil.dk/display/OFFSKOLELOGIN/Tilslut+tjeneste

Comment: Thanks, Anders...

But I just don't know what to do with the xml file after we give it a name (like this infrasup-98765_test_saml_metadata.xml)

Comment: As I remember you have to contact support to send the metadata file.